# How to create executable and IR at the same time

Tags: clang, llvm

I would like to create both the executable and LLVM IR using clang at the same time. Is there a way to do that?

I'm currently using

```
clang -flto -Wl,-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm -o foo foo.c
```

and get the error

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm'
```

with a -v invocation, I see that

```
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
```

Comment: after 3.7 it is renamed to "save-temps". it will create bitcode file which you can convert to llvm-ir using llvm-dis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both quite easily. Take a look at the tool:

https://github.com/SRI-CSL/whole-program-llvm